# Drag and Drop Jquery - Removing Draggable when it leaves grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT:

Does anyone know how to fix the flickering of the droppable area when the draggable goes over it? See what happens when you click grid, and drag fence piece above the paragraph thats above the grid. If I can fix this issue it would be a work around to my whole issue.. (a way to make draggable dissapear when leaving a specified non-droppable div).

I am using jquery drag and drop. I have a grid that the fence pieces can go on to. Please see [redacted]/dragndrop/3.html. If you click the borders of a square, the fence piece appears. If you drag the fence piece outside the grid to a specified droppable area (they are located in the left and right margins of the grid) I have a function that will remove them.

I would like the Draggable pieces to disappear when they leave the grid WITHOUT having to use droppable areas. Right now they will only disappear if I make other portions of the layout droppable, and then do something to the draggable items once they are dropped in the droppable areas outside the grid. In most cases, people make the draggable items dissapear when they leave the 'droppable' area. The problem with this is that every time the draggagble moves to a new droppable square on the grid, it is registering as leacing the droppable area.

Considering these issues I need a way to totally remove the draggable item if it leaves a specified div. This specified div should not need to be droppable. Right now as a work around I set up droppable areas on the left and right margins of the grid.

```
      $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            droppable = true;
            if(original){
                 var newDiv = $(ui.draggable);
                 //var newDiv = $(ui.draggable).clone();

                 newDiv.draggable({
                    stop: function( event, ui ) {
                        if(!droppable)
                            ui.helper.remove();
                    },
                    start: function( event, ui ) {
                        droppable = false;   
                    },
     });



    if  ($(this).hasClass('noHover')   )  {
         $(newDiv).remove();
    } 
     */

     //console.log('here we are' + $(this) );

    if  ($(this).hasClass('noHover')   )  {
         $(newDiv).remove();
    }

    if (!$(this).hasClass("col-xs-2 col-sm-2")) {
        //console.log('here we are' + $(this).text());
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
        console.log(  $(this) ) 
        $(newDiv).remove();
        $(newDiv).css("display", "none");
    }
    /*
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a work-around by removing the default UI hover and adding my own hover class to solve the flickering div problem (was caused by something in ui hover css). Instead of removing draggable when it leaves droppable area, I made the rest of the page droppable, so you can simply slide the fence pieces off the grid and drop them anywhere and then I have a function to remove them.